# PyGame background color is not changing

Tags: python, pygame

I cannot find, what is wrong with background, even with debugger it is not doing nothing

```py
#importing
from turtle import width
import pygame

#resolution
pygame.display.set_caption("Tanks")
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

#background color (my problem)
def draw_window():
    WIN.fill((255, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

#main functions
def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
    
    pygame.quit()

#game start
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `draw_window` is never called you have to call `draw_window` in the application loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `draw_window` in the application loop:

```py
#importing
import pygame

#resolution
pygame.display.set_caption("Tanks")
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#background color (my problem)
def draw_window():
    WIN.fill((255, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

#main functions
def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(100)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        draw_window()
    
    pygame.quit()

#game start
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Answer (score 0):

When you write a function, it is just some instructions on memory, it doesn't run unless you call it. This is the case. You write a set of instructions, `draw_window`, but you never call it. What you need to do is before the game loop, call `draw_window`. So the code would be something like this.

```
#importing
from turtle import width
import pygame

#resolution
pygame.display.set_caption("Tanks")
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

#background color (my problem)
def draw_window():
    WIN.fill((255, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

#main functions
def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        draw_window()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
    
    pygame.quit()

#game start :)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This way the result will be a red window which is rgb(0, 0).

Comment: Oh right sorry I'm used to it being outside. I'll edit

Comment: I edited it, it is inside the main function now.